# Set columnDefs dynamically

Tags: angularjs, ui-grid

Basically I have datatable with dyamic column header ( date format ), so I'm wondering how to set the columnDefs dynamically.

my data is like :

```
  $scope.data =   [{"FirstName":"Ali","8/11/2016 12:00:00 AM":"Yes" ;}]
```

and here is how i'm calling it :

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
        enableHorizontalScrollbar: 1,
        enableFiltering: true,
        paginationPageSizes: [150, 300, 450],
        paginationPageSize: 150,
        enableEditing: true,
        rowHeight: 110,
        data: data ,

    /*    columnDefs: [

       {  name: 'FirstName', field: 'FirstName', displayName: 'FirstName' , enableCellEdit: false  , width :'60' }

         ]*/
        };
```

PS: the data can have many columns with date format and i'm using angular 1.3

Comment: why you are not using `ng-repeat` ? to render data

Comment: I'm using a grid like this one
 <div id="grd" ui-grid="gridOptions"

Comment: You should use `ng-repeat` it is better choice

Comment: can you show an example using ng-repeat. i am still learning angular

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
Keep the headers on $scope and call them in columnDefs

```
$scope.headers = [
    FirstName:newFName
]
$scope.gridOptions = {
    enableHorizontalScrollbar: 1,
    enableFiltering: true,
    paginationPageSizes: [150, 300, 450],
    paginationPageSize: 150,
    enableEditing: true,
    rowHeight: 110,
    data: data ,
    columnDefs: [
        {field:'FirstName' , displayName: $scope.headers.displayName , enableCellEdit: false  , width :'60' }
        ];
```